# How to update any parameter value of existing java lombok Builder object?

Tags: java, lombok, builder

If I have a @Builder AnObj,

```
import lombok.Builder;

@Builder public class AnObj {

    private final String name;
    private final int age; 
}
```

with its properties (name, age), and there is an instance created

```
        AnObj a = AnObj.builder()
                .name("abc")
                .age(25)
                .build();
        System.out.println("anInstance: " + a.toBuilder().toString());
// Prints 
 anInstance: AnObj.AnObjBuilder(name=abc, age=25)
```

then how can I use the same object(*a*) but with an updated value in one of the parameter(say,  *age* to be 40)

I tried,

```
    a.toBuilder().age(40).build();
    System.out.println("anInstance after update: " + a.toBuilder().toString());

// Prints the same values again:
 anInstance after update: AnObj.AnObjBuilder(name=abc, age=25)
```

Expected result to be printed:

```
*// AnObj.AnObjBuilder(name=abc, age=40)*
```

Thanking in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `toBuilder.age(40).build()` you are not reassigning that to the instance.
The code should look like this:

```
a = a.toBuilder().age(40).build();
```

Let me know if it has been helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Thought I already tried this but had not.

Comment: In order to update those props(any) in the AnObj, we must have @@@Builder(toBuilder=true) attributes as well, no?, or is there any other way to update those properties without having toBuilder and/or @@@Setter anno..?